# How do i get data from recursive structure got from C function?

Tags: c, python-3.x, ctypes, hidapi

I'm writing a wrapper for usb hid device and want to use [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi) for that. In process of writing/learning got a pointer on recursive structure. How can i get data from this?

I tried to get data from `contents`, but there was only `_field_` inside.

C-struct and C-function from [hidapi](https://github.com/signal11/hidapi):

```
struct hid_device_info {
            /** Platform-specific device path */
            char *path;
            /** Device Vendor ID */
            unsigned short vendor_id;
            /** Device Product ID */
            unsigned short product_id;
            /** Serial Number */
            wchar_t *serial_number;
            /** Device Release Number in binary-coded decimal,
                also known as Device Version Number */
            unsigned short release_number;
            /** Manufacturer String */
            wchar_t *manufacturer_string;
            /** Product string */
            wchar_t *product_string;
            /** Usage Page for this Device/Interface
                (Windows/Mac only). */
            unsigned short usage_page;
            /** Usage for this Device/Interface
                (Windows/Mac only).*/
            unsigned short usage;
            /** The USB interface which this logical device
                represents. Valid on both Linux implementations
                in all cases, and valid on the Windows implementation
                only if the device contains more than one interface. */
            int interface_number;

            /** Pointer to the next device */
            struct hid_device_info *next;
        };

struct hid_device_info HID_API_EXPORT * HID_API_CALL hid_enumerate(unsigned short vendor_id, unsigned short product_id);
```

Python code:

```
import ctypes


class HidDeviceInfo(ctypes.Structure):
    pass

HidDeviceInfo._field_ = [
    ('path', ctypes.c_char_p),
    ('vendor_id', ctypes.c_ushort),
    ('product_id', ctypes.c_ushort),
    ('serial_number', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    ('release_number', ctypes.c_ushort),
    ('manufacturer_string', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    ('product_string', ctypes.c_wchar_p),
    ('usage_page', ctypes.c_ushort),
    ('usage', ctypes.c_ushort),
    ('interface_number', ctypes.c_int),
    ('next', ctypes.POINTER(HidDeviceInfo))
]


hid_api_dll = ctypes.CDLL("hidapi.dll")

def get_devs(vid, pid):
    hid_enumerate = hid_api_dll.hid_enumerate

    hid_api_dll.hid_enumerate.argtypes = [
        ctypes.c_ushort,
        ctypes.c_ushort
    ]
    hid_api_dll.hid_enumerate.restype = ctypes.POINTER(HidDeviceInfo)

    vid_t = ctypes.c_ushort(vid)
    pid_t = ctypes.c_ushort(pid)

    res = ctypes.POINTER(HidDeviceInfo)()

    res = hid_enumerate(vid_t, pid_t)
    return res


devs = get_devs(0x0, 0x0)
print(devs.contents)
frameInfo = devs.contents
print(frameInfo.path)
```

I try to just get `path` attribute from this and got `AttributeError: 'HidDeviceInfo' object has no attribute 'path'`.

There must be recursive list of all hid devices. How can i retrieve data? Or maybe i done something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - Structures and unions](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#structures-and-unions) (**emphasis** is mine):

> Structures and unions must derive from the [Structure](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Structure) and [Union](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.Union) base classes which are defined in the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module. Each subclass **must define a `_fields_` attribute**. `_fields_` must be a list of 2-*tuples*, containing a *field name* and a *field type*.

Replace *HidDeviceInfo._field_* to *HidDeviceInfo._field**s**_* (**plural**, **surrounded** by **one** *UnderScore* ("***_***")), and things should be fine.